# Cannot stream video over cabled connection, but Wifi works

Tags: networking, video-streaming

On my laptop (Windows 10), I can stream a video from the internet when it's connected over Wifi to my DSL modem, but not if it's connected with a cable to that same modem. 'Normal' internet works fine both ways.

I tried two different video providers (if it matters: npostart.nl and pathe-thuis.nl), both give error messages about something not being authorized. One is: *DRM: License error! --com.widevine.alpha update, XHR complete, status is "" (401), readyState is 4.* while the other just says *error 5*. (Using the browser's developer tools I can see that a request to *drm.providername/something/authorization* fails with status 401, so I assume both have in fact the same problem)

I tried different browsers (FF, Edge, Chrome), emptied caches, restarted the modem, restarted the laptop, but so far, nothing fixes the problem.

On a different PC (also Windows 10), that has only a cabled connection, both providers work.

What could cause this problem?